# Hide project from dbt docs

Tags: databricks, dbt

We have a dbt project with a single project folder. However, when running `dbt docs generate` and then serve up the results, two project folders are shown under Projects: Our project, and **dbt_spark**. The dbt_spark folder lists macros that are defined by the dbt-spark python package. Now, dbt-spark is a dependency for our project (we are using Databricks as backend), but none of the macros are used in our transformations.

Any ideas how to hide the dbt_spark - project? I guess it is possible to use sed to filter references to dbt_spark, but was hoping for a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the file manifest.json, there is a `"docs": {"show": true}` property for each `macro.dbt_spark.xxx´ macro-element in the file. I changed these elements to false with a short python-script. Now, only our own project is displayed under Projects...

Answer (score -1):

Just tweak your dbt_project.yaml

```
models:
  dbt_spark:
    +docs:
      show: false
  your_project:
```

Comment: I have tried using this config and as far as I can tell it does not actually hide the package, it still appears in the documentation.